# Google Search not properly indexing AJAX-loaded pages

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a static website which uses async jQuery to generate articles (as well as titles and other metadata) sourced from a file (something like `$('main').load('/data #location.pathname')`). The only problem seems to be that Google cannot accurately read these pages, as Google Search just returns the default title and description (even though the Google Search Console crawler bot seems to preview them fine). I've tried to look through Google's AJAX docs but they have been marked as deprecated for a few years and I can't find any superceding documentation. How can I get Google to properly index these pages?

Comment: By "the Google Search Console crawler bot' do you mean the "inspect URL tool" including the "live test"?

Comment: How long have the pages been on your site?

Comment: Are you using a single page application framework such as React or Angular?  If so have you looked into server side rendering?  It is always riskier for SEO to use AJAX compared to putting the data directly into the HTML for the file.     Googlebot does execute JavaScript now, but relying on JS for rendering can introduce crawler errors and delays.

Comment: 1) Yes 2) Around a week; I've seen the links be updated in Google, with the errors still in place 3) No, just JS and jQuery

Comment: Alright, it looked like I wouldn't be able to do this, so instead I made `/data/content` import the page layout from `/article` instead of `/article` importing the article content from `/data#content`.

Comment: It sounds like that solution may be better.   You could also just try waiting longer.   Googlebot makes two passes on AJAX powered sites.  First a pass to crawl just the HTML and then a second pass to fetch additional resources and render the page using JavaScript.   Although Google says the second pass should happen very quickly these days, it has sometimes had a delay of a month or more.  See [Flag my website as a single page application?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/122611/flag-my-website-as-a-single-page-application)